# Mod rewrite issue redirect with post

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In fact I am working on a small php script, and now I am struggling with doing redirect using mod-rewrite.
What i want is to redirect

```
www.xx.com/motivational/api.php?latest=1
```

to

```
www.xx.com/api.php?latest=1&app=motivational
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/motivational/api\.php$ /api.php?latest=&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{QUERY_STRING}` represents the entire query string, in your case `latest=1`. So when you append it to `...?latest=` in your substitution string the result is `...?latest=latest=1` which is not what you want.

Change your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^/motivational/api\.php$ /api.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&app=motivational
```

and you should be fine.

Or you could do:

```
RewriteRule ^/motivational/api\.php$ /api.php?app=motivational [QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag means to append the new query string to the old, rather than to replace it, so your `latest` variable will not be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can not match against query strings in a RewriteRule, You will need a RewriteCond to match query strings in url :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/api\.php\?latest=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /api.php?latest=1&app=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

%1 is part of the regex "([^/]+)" in RewriteCond, it contains dynmically captured path in the request line.